# Kafka Stream using SpecificAvroSerde in Java Could not find class error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am preparing an Kafka Stream application with Java. The task is consuming some messages from a topic which contains message generated by JDBC connector with

`io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter` as Key and Value Converter.

The messages can be consumed by using `bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer` in command mode without any issue.

I have generated the class (named myobject) in my IDE by using Maven Plug-in and the generated class are sitting under

`{project}/target/generated-sourcess/avro/com.myproject.myclasses/myobject`

In my Main Class, i can create the object by using myobject class without any issue.

I have imported that generated class in my main class

```
import com.myproject.myclasses.myobject;
```

I have following configurations in my stream application

```
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,this.applicaionId);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,svrConfig.getBootstrapServers());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");       
    config.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, svrConfig.getCacheMaxBytesBufferingConfig());       
    config.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class);
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    config.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
```

In my stream builder script, I have

```
    final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url","http://localhost:8081");
    Serdes.StringSerde keySpecificAvroSerde = new Serdes.StringSerde();
    final Serde<myObject> valueSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    valueSpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, myObject> purchaseInvoices = builder.stream(this.sourceTopic
            , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueSpecificAvroSerde));
```

I received the following error below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class mybject specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

According to my testing, I believe the application can extract the record from my topic. Moreover, when I use GenericAvroSerde approach, everything works fine and i can consume the message successfully. However, GenericAvroSerde approach need to have extra lines to map the message from Kafka topic in myObject and I assume SpecificAvroSerde approach can save that part of mapping so that I really want to have SpecificAvroSerde approach works.

Any advice? Is that I put myObject in a wrong place so that my application (I just run in my local IDE with the Confluent under the same machine) cannot locate myObject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this example that uses `SpecifcAvroSerde`: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.1.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroExample.java

Comment: Thanks Matthias. It works if i follow EXACTLY the same as the example (which the topic created by using the WikipediaFeedAvroExampleDriver.java) . However, to my case, as my topic and the schema is not created in that way but using a JDBC connectors. After reviewing the differences of the schema created by WikipediaFeedAvroExampleDriver.java and the one by my connector. I found that the schema created by WikipediaFeedAvroExampleDriver.java contains the namespace. However, the one created by my JDBC connector does not. I think this is the reason why I receive the error.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of the JDBC connector. If it does not register the schema correctly, you need to either update the schema in the registry manually, or switch to a different Serde type. Maybe GenericAvroSerde works? Or you need to pass the schema to the SpecialAvroSerde manually instead of getting it from the schema registry?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax!! I have update the schema by adding the namespace but it does not work. In fact, it works well if I use "GenericAvroSerde" approach. What do you mean by "pass the schema to SpecificAvroSerde"? Any sample can I refer to?

Comment: I meant generic... Sorry (cf. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/find/4.1.0-post) -- the repo contains multiple AVRO examples -- just search for files with containing "avro" in their name.

Comment: Thanks so much ~ @MatthiasJ.Sax! I will have a look of the link you shared. I am considering to try to create the scheme by using the "Producer" at first. Then, try to do some scheme evolution and see how it goes~

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue.  In my case, the writer's schema has been registered with the keyword 'public' in the namespace name so it resolves to an illegal package name that I cannot assign to my generated implementation.

I'd like to try giving the SpecificAvroSerde an instance of my reader's schema with the corrected namespace, but there does not seem to be any interface support for doing so...

Comment: There IS support in the underlyiing KafkaAvroDeserializer's deserialize() method for passing it a reader's schema, but no code path through Stream's SpecificAvroSerde calls that method.  It looks possible too subclass SpecifcAvroSerde to accept a reader's schema and override the deserialize method to use it.  That's what I'm attempting too do now.

There is also a name to Class HashMap in the SpecificData class, but that's too private protected to attempt aliasng my classes there.

Comment: For a more up-to-date tutorial, I've found https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.3/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#streams-data-avro
to be useful.